# When transfering data from the cell of one sheet to another i am given #ref! error. how do i fix this?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

when importing info from cell K24 in a google sheet called "Kaila Crowe-Weekly Timesheet" into a a different google sheet. when i use =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1km-rgr3fWQpnxV_IOjvfBeWYHwcSMKGCQ5vI3DUkh-Y/edit#gid=0","Kaila Crowe-Weekly Timesheet!D10:F10"). why would I be running into this error if all info is correctly labeled?

Comment: Did you hover over the #Ref error?  When you use IMPORTRANGE, most of the time you will have to hover over the error and click ALLOW, to give it permission to import the data.  It is a security feature.

Comment: correct. i have allowed permission already. still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.  When referencing a sheet that has spaces in the name, you have to surround the name in single quotes.  So your range should look like this:

`'Kaila Crowe-Weekly Timesheet'!D10:F10`

Which you then put inside the double quotes of the formula:

`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1km-rgr3fWQpnxV_IOjvfBeWYHwcSMKGCQ5vI3DUkh-Y/edit#gid=0", "'Kaila Crowe-Weekly Timesheet'!D10:F10")`

See if that works.

Comment: unfortunately that gave me the same error

Comment: Check if the name of the reference tab has no space at the end!

Comment: Does the error give you any context when you hover over it?